# re-arrangement of a formula (regula falsi)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am told

$$ \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}=\frac{c-b}{c-a} \tag 1$$

which should give me

$$ c= \frac{af(b)-bf(a)}{f(b)-f(a)} \tag 2$$

or alternatively

$$ c= a + \frac{f(a)(a-b)}{f(b)-f(a)} \tag 3$$

But every time I rearrange the first equation I get

$$ c= \frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{f(a)-f(b)} \tag 4$$

and I am not sure how to get the third equation.

Could someone explain please?

Comment: To get from $(4)$ to $(2)$, multiply top and and bottom by $-1$. To get from $(3)$ to $(4)$, just put everything under the same denominator.

Comment: But that would require c to be multiplied by -1 also?

Comment: No, you're actually multiplying by $1$ on both sides, only on the RHS you disguise $1$ as $\frac {-1}{-1}$.

Comment: amazing!  What exactly do you mean by put everything under the same denominator?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2646279 I mean $a + \dfrac{f(a)(a-b)}{f(b)-f(a)}=\dfrac{a(f(b)-f(a))}{f(b)-f(a)} + \dfrac{f(a)(a-b)}{f(b)-f(a)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is an answer to an earlier version of the question, in which there was a typo. At that time, it said "$f(a)/f(b) = \frac{c-b}{c-a}$", for which the answer below is, I think, correct.

---

You should get $c(f(a) - f(b)) = b f(b) - a f(a)$. Either you miscopied, or your book/teacher is wrong, or my algebra is way off.

Basically, you multiply through by the common denominator to get

$$
(c-a) f(a) = (c-b) f(b)
$$
Expand to get
$$
c f(a)- af(a) = c f(b) - b f(b)
$$
Swap sides for some terms to get
$$
c f(a)- cf(b) = a f(a) - b f(b) \\
c (f(a)- f(b)) = a f(a) - b f(b) \\
c = \frac{a f(a) - b f(b)}{f(a)- f(b)}
$$

Note that the $ab$ terms have $a f(a)$ and $b f(b)$, not $a f(b)$ and $b f(a)$.

If the original equation had $f(b)/f(a)$ on the left, I think that it would all work out, however.

Comment: Thanks, i copied it out wrong! ... it is f(b)/f(a).  Which I guess means it is wrong in my book.  How would I get from 3 to 4?

Comment: If you want to have the terms with a and b in one place, write it as $$c=\frac{|f(a)|^{-1}a+|f(b)|^{-1}b}{|f(a)|^{-1}+|f(b)|^{-1}}$$ so that it looks like a convex combination with the *inverse* function values as weights.

Comment: The first statement of the comment above should have been: This answer is wrong. The formulas in the question are all correct. If you want to write down a formula with the terms with a resp. b clustered together, write the original formula as ... ... This is possible since $0<-\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}=\frac{|f(a)|}{|f(b)|}$.

Comment: I've edited my answer -- the question, when I answered it, had a typo. (See the poster's comment from 4/7, 17:51).  When I answered the question, it said "$f(a)/f(b) = \frac{c-b}{c-a}$", for which my answer was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this so I can select an answer, the solution was provided by Git Gud as a comment.

To get from (4) to (2), multiply both sides by $ \frac{-1}{-1} $.  On the LHS this is the same as multiplication by 1, so it stays the same, on the RHS it changes as required.

To get from (2) to (3) note that

$$ c= a + \frac{f(a)(a-b)}{f(b)-f(a)} = \frac{a(f(b)-f(a))}{f(b)-f(a)} + \frac{f(a)(a-b)}{f(b)-f(a)}\tag 1$$